# Java Refuses to detect any class libraries

Tags: java, class, types

This feels extremely like a duplicate of another problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution. In both Eclipse(Java) and JGrasp, no matter what I do, the IDE refuses to compile the class libraries I have with it.

I have already attempted to add the libraries manually in Eclipse with the build path configuration, creating a folder in the workspace, copying the class files into it, then adding that folder to the Classpath.

In JGrasp, I have read that simply having the class file in the same directory as the runner file is sufficient.

```
public class PayrollLoop
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    // Prepare to receive output
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // initialize variables
    int numberEmployees = 0;
    double totalGrossPay = 0;
    double averagePay = 0;

    Payroll employee = new Payroll();
    String repeat = "yes";

    // Loop to ask for repeated entry of employees.
    // New String method: stringObject.equals(anotherStringObject). 
    // This method returns a boolean value of True or False.

    while ( repeat.equals("yes") )  
    {
        // prompt and scan for employee name        
        System.out.print("Enter the name:   ");
        employee.setName( scan.next() );

        // prompt and scan for ID number
        System.out.print("Enter the id number:  ");
        employee.setIdNumber( scan.nextInt() );

        // prompt and scan for pay rate
        System.out.print("Enter the pay rate:   ");
        employee.setPayRate( scan.nextDouble() );

        // prompt and scan for hours worked
        System.out.print("Enter the number of hours worked: ");
        employee.setHoursWorked(scan.nextDouble());


        // what should you do to the numberEmployees variable here?
         numberEmployees ++;

        // what should you do to the totalGrossPay variable here?



        // use the getter methods to print all the employee values
        System.out.println("Name                " + employee.getName());
        System.out.println("Id number           " + employee.getIdNumber());
        System.out.println("Pay Rate            " + employee.getPayRate());
        System.out.println("Hours Worked        " + employee.getHoursWorked());
        System.out.println("Gross Pay           " + employee.grossPay());
        System.out.println();

        // Ask user if entering another and scan for response
        System.out.println();



    } // end of the while loop  



    // calculate average pay
    averagePay = totalGrossPay / numberEmployees;



    // print average pay
    System.out.println("The average pay is: " + averagePay);




    } // end of main method    
}
```

jGASP error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g PayrollLoop.java
 ----   at: Oct 8, 2019, 1:15:39 PM

 ----jGRASP wedge: pid for wedge is 2648.
 ----jGRASP wedge2: pid for wedge2 is 784.
 ----jGRASP wedge2: CLASSPATH is ";.;;;C:\Program Files (x86)\jGRASP\extensions\classes".
 ----jGRASP wedge2: working directory is [H:\APCS\2019-2020 AP Computer Science\Unit 2\payrolltest] platform id is 2.
 ----jGRASP wedge2: actual command sent ["C:\Program Files\jdk-10.0.2\bin\javac.exe" -g PayrollLoop.java].
 ----jGRASP wedge2: pid for process is 5304.

PayrollLoop.java:35: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println("Enter the pay rate:     ")
                                                      ^
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Class file is already compiled.

Comment: Please copy/paste the **exact** error message here in your question. Also show which line causes the error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I edited the error in, but that wasn't the exact same error I was getting before.

Comment: @DevilsHnd employee isn't recognized

Comment: Make sure your dependent jar library files are added to your project. **1)** Right click on your project. **2)** Select Build Path. **3)** Click on Configure Build Path. **4)** Click on Libraries and select Add External JARs. **5)** Select the jar file from the required folder. **6)** Click Apply and Ok.

Comment: The error you posted occurs in a class named `Main`, but you posted a class named `PayrollLoop`.

Comment: Post the file that actually contains the line with the error. The error message complains about an `Employee` class but you are not using any `Employee` class in the `PayrollLoop` code you posted.

Comment: For java, the file path typically needs to match the package name.  So, if `waltz.death.MyClass` is in a file called `MyClass.class`, it should also be under directory structure `waltz/death/`

Comment: I have done both already. Anything new?

Comment: I wish more people would see this, maybe get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jGRASP, turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages", then the output of compilation will also show the classpath. There may be something weird about your classpath.

Make sure Employee.class is named correctly (proper case, no hidden additional extension).

If Employee is in a package, you need to replicate that package structure as a directory structure, so if it is in package "company", you need a directory named "company" in the directory containing "Main" (or elsewhere on the classpath), and Employee.class would be in that directory.

If you do have a .jar version of this library, you can use "Settings" > "PATH / CLASSPATH" > "Workspace" (or "Project ..." if you are using projects) to add it to the classpath in jGRASP.

Comment: I had already added the class files to the classpath. I tried again. Still doesn't work.

Comment: OK, please post the verbose output from a compile.

Comment: Is that not what I have at the end of the question?

Comment: Turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages", then post all of the output from a failed compile, not just the Java error message.

Comment: I don't see settings. I'm in eclipse.

Comment: My suggestions are in reference to jGRASP. It will probably be easier to figure out what is going wrong from there than in Eclipse.

Comment: ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Person cannot be resolved to a type
 Person cannot be resolved to a type

 at PersonTestFile.main(PersonTestFile.java:11)```

Comment: That is not the normal "not on the classpath" compiler error message. Is "Person" directly referenced at PersonTestFile.java:11?

Comment: Also, please post the entire output, including the compile command and verbose details which includes the classpath.

Comment: That is the entire output. Yes, Person is directly referenced.

Comment: Is this still Eclipse? The compile output in jGRASP starts with the command, ends with "operation complete", and in verbose mode includes the actual command sent including resolved absolute path to executable, classpath, and working directory. Anyway, lets continue this off-thread. Use "Help" > "Report a Bug" in jGRASP and send that output, and make sure to include your email. The report will get to me.

Comment: Added the full jGRASP error to the question @lbarowski

Comment: It looks like you're all good with the classpath in jGRASP, you just need to fix the syntax error in your code, which doesn't seem to be there in the source code you posted.

Comment: No sir, the unexpected character is the P in Person because it is not reading Person as a type, due to the class not being compiled with the code.